# Connect-ADAccount with service principal: Insufficient privileges to perform requested operation

Tags: azure, powershell

I need to be able to run `Connect-ADAccount` in a non-interactive mode, invite a user to my AD, assign some resource permissions to this new user.

So I have:

Created a service principal.

Created a certificate using the following code:

```
Connect-AzureAD 
$Certname = Read-Host "Enter Certificate Name"
$Cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -certstorelocation cert:\localmachine\my -dnsname $Certname -Provider “Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider”
$pw = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Pazzword" -Force -AsPlainText
$thumbprint = $Cert.Thumbprint

Export-PfxCertificate -cert cert:\localMachine\my\$thumbprint -FilePath $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\$Certname.pfx -Password $pw

Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\$Certname.pfx | Export-Certificate -FilePath 
$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\OutputCert.crt -Type Cert
```

Uploaded it manually.

Gave owner permissions to my service principal.

Now I am able to run the following code but it would fail on the `New-AzureADMSInvitation` step.

```
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $ObjectId -ApplicationId  $AppId -CertificateThumbprint $thumb

New-AzureADMSInvitation -InvitedUserDisplayName $userName -InvitedUserEmailAddress $userEmail -InviteRedirectUrl 'https://portal.azure.com/' -SendInvitationMessage $true
```

I am not sure what would be the required permissions in this case.

```
New-AzureADMSInvitation : Error occurred while executing NewAzureADMSInvitation 
Code: Unauthorized
Message: Insufficient privileges to perform requested operation by the application '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'. ControllerName=MSGraphInviteAPI, ActionName=CreateInvite [...]
```

Comment: You gave owner permissions on what to your service principal?

Answer (score 0):

`New-AzureADMSInvitation` invoke [Create invitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) MS Graph API in the backend.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations
```

You need to add one of the following **application permission** when using service principal:

- User.Invite.All,
- User.ReadWrite.All,
- Directory.ReadWrite.All

Please navigate to App registration > your app > add API Permissions > Microsoft Graph API > Select the previous in Application Permission. And also remember to grant admin consent for your tenant.